# Parallelism within concurrentPerform closure

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, swift5

I am looking to implement concurrency inside part of my app in order to speed up processing. The input array can be a large array, that I need to check multiple things related to it. This would be some sample code.

EDITED:
So this is helpful for looking at striding through the array, which was something else I was looking at doing, but I think the helpful answers are sliding away from the original question, due to the fact that I already have a `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform` present in the code.

Within a for loop multiple times, I was looking to implement other for loops, due to having to relook at the same data multiple times. The `inputArray` is an array of structs, so in the outer loop, I am looking at one value in the struct, and then in the inner loops I am looking at a different value in the struct. In the change below I made the two inner for loops function calls to make the code a bit more clear. But in general, I would be looking to make the two `funcA` and `funcB` calls, and wait until they are both done before continuing in the main loop.

```swift
//assume the startValues and stop values will be within the bounds of the

//array and wont under/overflow
private func funcA(inputArray: [Int], startValue: Int, endValue: Int) -> Bool{
    for index in startValue...endValue {
        let dataValue = inputArray[index]
        
        if dataValue == 1_000_000 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

private func funcB(inputArray: [Int], startValue: Int, endValue: Int) -> Bool{
    for index in startValue...endValue {
        let dataValue = inputArray[index]
        
        if dataValue == 10 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

private func testFunc(inputArray: [Int]) {
    let dataIterationArray = Array(Set(inputArray))
    let syncQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "syncQueue")
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: dataIterationArray.count) { index in
                
        //I want to do these two function calls starting roughly one after another,
        //to work them in parallel, but i want to wait until both are complete before
        //moving on. funcA is going to take much longer than funcB in this case,
        //just because there are more values to check.
        let funcAResult = funcA(inputArray: dataIterationArray, startValue: 10, endValue: 2_000_000)
        let funcBResult = funcB(inputArray: dataIterationArray, startValue: 5, endValue: 9)
        //Wait for both above to finish before continuing
        
        if funcAResult && funcBResult {
            print("Yup we are good!")
        } else {
            print("Nope")
        }
        
        //And then wait here until all of the loops are done before processing
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question here? This is what `concurrentPerform` does already. Just make 3 iterations and in each work on `value * index`. The "then wait here" happens after `concurrentPerform`. For the vast majority of real problems, this is actually much more complex, and difficult to make fast, than you've presented here, but knowing the deeper problem is likely critical to solving it performantly (in many cases, the right answer is to redesign to use Accelerate or something similar, which is not the same thing as GCD). Note that all of this is unrelated to "Swift Concurrency."

Comment: concurrentPerform runs all contents of the outer for loop in parallel to the max number of threads. But inside that, I have to iterate large loops of data multiple times to pull different pieces of data out. I would want the outer for loop to spin up what it needs to, then kick each of the inner for loops off in parallel, so that it doesn't have to wait for the first inner for loop to finish before starting the next for loop

Comment: What `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform` does is it takes all threads available to the app (lets say 10) and puts iteration 1...10 on each thread. When one thread is done, it will schedule the next iteration (11) on that thread, and so on. BUT: you may have 10 threads, but how many CPUs do you have? if your calculation is CPU-intensive, then your performance is not as much dependant on threads as on CPUs. So you need to limit `concurrentPerform` by number of CPUs, and even then you may still be limited, since some CPUs may be busy doing something else

Comment: So you need to get `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform` have only 2...[max CPUs] iterations, and inside them loop through big chunks of array

Comment: Also consider using GPUs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/performing_calculations_on_a_gpu

Comment: I am still new to this topic. so not sure if I am speaking correctly, but the issues isn't necessarily with .concurrentPerform. I am aware I am taking overhead to spin up a new thread on the CPU to perform operations. 

each of the inner for loops deals with different subset array of the larger array, that do not interact with each other. so I want those tasks to also happen in parallel

Answer (score 2):

In your revised question, you contemplated a `concurrentPerform` loop where each iteration called `funcA` and then `funcB` and suggested that you wanted them “to work them in parallel”.

Unfortunately. that is not how [`concurrentPerform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2016088-concurrentperform/) works. It runs the separate iterations in parallel, but the code within the closure should be synchronous and run sequentially. If the closure introduces additional parallelism, that will adversely affect how the `concurrentPerform` can reason about how many worker threads it should use.

Before we consider some alternatives, let us see what will happen if `funcA` and `funcB` remain synchronous. In short, you will still enjoy parallel execution benefits.

Below, I logged this with “Points of Interest” intervals in Instruments, and you will see that `funcA` (in green) never runs concurrently with `funcB` (in purple) for the same iteration (i.e., for the same range of `start` and `end` indices). In this example, I am processing an array with 180 items, striding 10 items at a time, ending up with 18 iterations running on an iPhone 12 Pro Max with six cores:

[image]

But, as you can see, although `funcB` for a given range of indices will not start until `funcA` finishes for the same range of indices, it does not really matter, because we are still enjoying full parallelism on the device, taking advantage of all the CPU cores.

I contend that, given that we are enjoying parallelism, that there is little benefit to contemplate making `funcA` and `funcB` run concurrently with respect to each other, too. Just let the individual iterations run parallel to each other, but let A and B run sequentially, and call it a day.

If you *really* want to have `funcA` and `funcB` run parallel with each other, as well, you will need to consider a different pattern. The `concurrentPerform` simply is not designed for launching parallel tasks that, themselves, are asynchronous. You could consider:

- Have `concurrentPerform` launch, using my example, 36 iterations, half of which do `funcA` and half of which do `funcB`.
- Or you might consider using `OperationQueue` with a reasonable `maxConcurrentOperationCount` (but you do not enjoy the dynamic limitation of the degree concurrency to the device’s CPU cores).
- Or you might use an `async`-`await` task group, which will limit itself to the cooperative thread pool.

But you will not want to have `concurrentPerform` have a closure that launches asynchronous tasks or introduces additional parallel execution.

And, as I discuss below, the example provided in the question is not a good candidate for parallel execution. Mere tests of equality are not computationally intensive enough to enjoy parallelism benefits. It will undoubtedly just be slower than the serial pattern.

---

My original answer, below, outlines the basic `concurrentPerform` considerations.

---

The basic idea is to “stride” through the values. So calculate how many “iterations” are needed and calculate the “start” and “end” index for each iteration:

```swift
private func testFunc(inputArray: [Int]) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let array = Array(Set(inputArray))
        let syncQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "syncQueue")

        // calculate how many iterations will be needed

        let count = array.count
        let stride = 10
        let (quotient, remainder) = count.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: stride)
        let iterations = remainder == 0 ? quotient : quotient + 1

        // now iterate

        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: iterations) { iteration in

            // calculate the `start` and `end` indices

            let start = stride * iteration
            let end = min(start + stride, count)

            // now loop through that range

            for index in start ..< end {
                let value = array[index]
                print("iteration =", iteration, "index =", index, "value =", value)
            }
        }

        // you won't get here until they're all done; obviously, if you 
        // want to now update your UI or model, you may want to dispatch
        // back to the main queue, e.g.,
        //
        // DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        //     ...
        // }
    }
}
```

Note, if something is so slow that it merits `concurrentPerform`, you probably want to dispatch the whole thing to a background queue, too. Hence the `DispatchQueue.global().async {…}` shown above. You would probably want to add a completion handler to this method, now that it runs asynchronously, but I will leave that to the reader.

---

Needless to say, there are quite a few additional considerations:

- The stride should be large enough to ensure there is enough work on each iteration to offset the modest overhead introduced by multithreading. Some experimentation is often required to empirically determine the best striding value.
- The work done in each thread must be significant (again, to justify the multithreading overhead). I.e., simply printing values is obviously not enough. (Worse, `print` statements compound the problem by introducing a hidden synchronization.) Even building a new array with some simple calculation will not be sufficient. This pattern really only works if you are doing something very computationally intensive.
- You have a “sync” queue, which suggests that you understand that you need to synchronize the combination of the results of the various iterations. That is good. I will point out, though, that you will want to minimize the total number of synchronizations you do. E.g. let’s say you have 1000 values and you end up doing 10 iterations, each striding through 100 values.  You generally want to have each iteration build a local result and do a single synchronization for each iteration. Using my example, you should strive to end up with only 10 total synchronizations, not 1000 of them, otherwise excessive synchronization can easily negate any performance gains.

Bottom line, making a routine execute in parallel is complicated and you can easily find that the process is actually slower than the serial rendition. Some processes simply don’t lend themselves to parallel execution. We obviously cannot comment further without understanding what your processes entail. Sometimes other technologies, such as [Accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/) or [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/) can achieve better results.

Comment: I edited the question to try and make what I was looking for more clear

Comment: @mikemgg123 - see revised/expanded answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain it here, since comment is too small, but will delete later if it doesn't answer the question.

Instead of looping over `iterations: dataIterationArray.count`, have number of iterations based on **number of desired parallel streams of work**, not based on array size. For example as you mentioned you want to have 3 streams of work, then you should have 3 iterations, each iteration processing independent part of work:

```
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 3) { iteration in 
    switch iteration {
    case 0:
        for i in 1...10{
            print ("i \(i)")
        }
    case 1:
        for j in 11...20{
            print ("j \(j)")
        }
    case 2:        
        for k in 21...30{
            print ("k \(k)")
        }
    }
}
```

And the "And then wait here until all of the loops are done before processing" will happen automatically, this is what concurrentPerform guarantees.